# Load SWF files from Cache permanently?

Tags: firefox, internet, swf

My question simply is how can I save My internet Browser cache(FireFox and Google Chrome) that I can reset this cache file any time explorer removes it?

I asked this question because my Internet connection is dial up(slow), when I load a big flash game (Like Cityville in facebook) it takes long time, and saved in cache, after a while swf load it self again, how can I save this swfs File in cache that it never loaded again and just run from cache (localhost), any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The [BetterCache](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bettercache/) addon for Firefox may do what you need.